# pthread scheduling

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, scheduling

I have a project about "simulating a thread scheduler with pthread".

I found several problems:
**1.** Is the thread lifecycle is the same as linux thread lifecyle?
**2.** In which step of code does scheduling happen (in pthreads), need an example.
**3.** Can I implement my own scheduling algorithm or I must use the explicit scheduling of pthreads like (set_sched_param, ...)?
**4.** Is there a way to trace process scheduling (graphically) using C?

Comment: A2: scheduling happens during a timer interrupt service routine. Among other things that happen then, the system evaluates how much run time the current thread has received to determine if it has exceeded its allowable run time and, if so, another thread takes its place (_if_ another thread is ready to run).

Comment: ...so in other-words, scheduling happens at the *kernel* level, and everything you're doing is in user-space.

Comment: @mah 'scheduling happens during a timer interrupt service routine'.  What about all the other dozens of hardware and software interrupt sources that can request a scheduler run?

Comment: @MartinJames how much completeness did you want a comment (as opposed to a posted answer) to carry? The _primary_ reason a scheduler runs is timer interrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that what you're after is simulating a scheduler for some OS, using pthreads as the basis for your implementation. What you can do is to create a pthread for each simulated thread, and put an implicit wait on a condition variable in each of the threading primitives of your OS. You can then, by picking which condition variable to signal, decide which thread gets to run when. I'm glossing over the details (ask if you want more info), but it's fairly straight-forward to implement.

Comment: Thank you for this reply but I wanna more info or sample code please.  That's will be the key of my work .What about explicit scheduling in pthread ?( with sched.h ) . To summarize , so we have2 solutions :   1/ condition variables 2/ pthread exmplicit scheduling , is it like that ?

Comment: Yes, these are different solutions. You may get better performance using explicit scheduling, but more precise control using manual scheduling using CVs etc. I'll see if I can write up some sample code and link that here.

Comment: Thank you very much , I am waiting :)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/manual-scheduling/ The code is crap (no error handling, fixed limits everywhere, and most likely full of bugs), but it illustrates the concept.

Comment: Google code is shutting down. Moved the code to Gitlab, in case anyone stumbles across this topic some day: https://gitlab.com/magnusr/manual-scheduling